# prevent table, table-striped etc classes with bootstrap5

Tags: css, bootstrap-table, bootstrap-5

Using bootstrap5.0.0-beta3 and bootstrap-table 1.18.2 (currently the most recent in webjars).

This is my code:

```
<table id="table">...</table> <!-- no classes here -->
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    url:dataUrl
});
```

But bootstrap-table is adding extra classes. This is the resulting DOM:

```
<div class="bootstrap-table bootstrap5">
   ...
   <div class="fixed-table-body">
      <div class="fixed-table-loading table table-bordered table-hover">
         <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">...
```

I don't want the table-bordered and table-hover classes. How can I avoid this (and why are they being added in the first place)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply just remove it. It's just a style bootstrap has. You don't need it.

Comment: The [Bootstrap-table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) extension for Bootstrap is intended for use with [Bootstrap 4](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start), not version 5. There’s nothing in their blog about making a version for Bootstrap 5 as yet. If you really want to use Bootstrap-table, do you need to use Bootstrap 5?

Comment: Its still there https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/

Comment: @JeromeMoores not so "simple" but still doable - it means writing a script that runs only after the table has been loaded, then remove all the classes from the relevant DOM elements. For each and every table.

Comment: @RichDeBourke ok so it's a clear incompatibility

Comment: Following @JeromeMoores ' suggestion:
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('table').on('load-success.bs.table', function (e) {
  $(e.currentTarget).removeClass("table-bordered table-hover");
 });
});